# Changing persistenceUnit properties during runtime

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a Spring MVC + Hibernate + JPA app.
I hava a `defaultPersistance` unit, that is defined in **persistence.xml**:

```
<persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=B3;" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="hiber1" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="hiber1" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I have an `entityManagerFactory` and `transactionManager` wired in **mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

So my question is: how can I change hibernate connection properties (eg. hibernate.connection. username) during runtime?

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: When you say runtime, do you mean while the application is running, or during deploy time of application?

Comment: I mean I want to change it while the app is running. I need it to make an authentication to database under different database users.

Comment: What properties do you need to change? Just the username?

Comment: Also, do you have the option to take out the database settings from persistence.xml and create a datasource managed by Spring?

Comment: If you need to switch the authentication, this should probably be thread per thread and not globally. You shouldn't be looking at that but more a custom `DataSource` wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider managing the datasource outside `persistence.xml` and use [`UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter.html) and its [`setCredentialsForCurrentThread`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter.html#setCredentialsForCurrentThread-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method.

Something around these lines:

```
    <bean id="targetDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> 
        <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=B3;" />
    </bean>


   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter"> 
      <property name="targetDataSource" ref="targetDataSource"/> 
      <property name="username" value="defaultUser"/> 
      <property name="password" value="mypassword" /> 
   </bean>
```

And in your java code you would get a reference to `dataSource` and call `setCredentialsForCurrentThread(username, password)`. Every time the datasource has `getConnection()` called on it, the credentials are checked against the current thread and those are used to get the connection.

Comment: Thanks You very much, I'll try this, it looks like a solution!

Comment: What would this look like as annotated classes rather than markup language?